# Properties of a continuous operator in $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

A book I am reading contains the following remark:

> We leave it as an exercivse to check that $T: l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ defined by $$T(\{x_n\}) = \{x_n/n\} \quad \forall\{x_n\} \in l^2$$
>   is continuous but does not have a closed image and is not open.

I am confused by this statement, doesn't this contradict closed graph and open mapping theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have a misunderstanding of those two theorems.

The closed graph theorem says that if $T : \ell_2 \to \ell_2$ is continuous and linear then the set $\{(x, y) \in \ell_2^2 : T(x)=y\}$ is closed.  That's different from asking that the image of $T$ is closed.

The open mapping theorem says that if $T : \ell_2 \to \ell_2$ is continuous, linear, *and surjective*, then $T$ is an open mapping.  The function you've got here isn't surjective (for instance, the sequence $(1/n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is not in the image of $T$).

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this, could you provide more detail on how $T$ is continuous, $T$ does not have a closed image, and $T$ is not open?